# Using an array to search active sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a worksheet which is updated regularly with details of duplicate records from a database.

I am trying to create a macro which searches for particular records however as I am new to Excel VBA I am struggling.

The code I currently have is as follows:
there are more names (21 to be precise but to save time I have removed these)

```
Dim rg As Range
Dim lnglastrow As Long
Dim intnamemax As Integer
Dim strName() As String


intnamemax = 21
ReDim strName(1 To intnamemax)

 strName(1) = "Bob Smith"
 strName(2) = "Rhys Jones"
 strName(3) = "Rebecca Hickling"

 lnglastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

 For Each rg In Range("A2:A" & lnglastrow)
    For i = 1 To intnamemax
        Set c = rg.Find(strName(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
           If Not c Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & found.Address
           Else
            MsgBox "No Proxy Candidates Found ", vbOKOnly, "Success!"
           End If
        Next i
    Next

End Sub
```

the Macro will run however when testing I get the msgbox no proxy candidates found despite there being an entry for one of the names.

I am struggling to figure out where I have gone wrong and would appreciate any help.

Comment: copy one of the names from the `strName` array and paste in the cell `A2' and see if it works

Comment: should found.address be c.address?  you can do this with a formua, something like this `=INDEX(IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$6)>0,($A$1:$A$6 & " at " & ROW($B$1:$B$6))),ROWS($D$1:$D1))` data to be checked is in A, column to check is B and the results are in the column you've put this in, the column D, is a way of ascending the count, when you drag down.  This is an array formula, so use CTRL SHIFT and ENTER.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav unfortunately the worksheet is way to big for a formula plus the user isnt great on excel (with formulas etc) and wants it to be automated.

Comment: ok, if you're sure.

Comment: also, just for testing, replace `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` in the code with a number such as 10 and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull the false return out of the loop, Or you will get at least 20 false even if one matches.

And you do not need the exterior loop as the FIND will look at the whole range as one.

```
Dim lnglastrow As Long
Dim intnamemax As Integer
Dim strName() As String
Dim fnd As Boolean

intnamemax = 21

ReDim strName(1 To intnamemax)

 strName(1) = "Bob Smith"
 strName(2) = "Rhys Jones"
 strName(3) = "Rebecca Hickling"

 lnglastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To intnamemax
    Set c = Range("A2:A" & lnglastrow).Find(strName(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & c.Address
        fnd = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
If Not fnd Then
    MsgBox "No Proxy Candidates Found ", vbOKOnly, "Success!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried your code with one of the names pasted and unfortunately still no joy it's as if the value doesn't exist within the column even though it does. Unless the value is in cell A2

Comment: Are you sure they are spelled the same and the data does not have extra unseen characters like spaces?

Comment: The data is copied so will always be the same and @slayernoah i will try that hopefully it works!

Comment: I have tried the code again and this works! however this only finds the first instance instead of continuing to search. As I am not 100% sure and do not want to break something that currently works how would I search for **all**  instances

Comment: Remove the `Exit For`